# New to MVVM: how to workout the View

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I've just got 3 classes: Topic, Example and Exercise. Topic is the main class where both Example and Exercise is linked to. In my window (non-MVVM) I am populating a listbox with my topics, and upon selecting an item in the listbox where the topics are bound to, I am getting the ID of that topic and again populating 2 listboxes (for examples and exercises) related to that topic.

As I am new to MVVM and still trying to understand it, I am at lost on how to convert this to MVVM. Should I have 3 views (3 usercontrols?) for each 3 classes (models)? In my current setting they are all in 1 window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is entirely up to you.

How do you normally split state and behavior across classes? There is no 'extra' rule for that in MVVM.

Think of reuse and single responsibility. This is applicable for View, ViewModel and Model classes.

It is possible to compose a View, ViewModel and Model out of multiple classes.

One thing I learned is that although it is possible to reuse a ViewModel for multiple Views (in fact some introductions to MVVM state that as benefit) I found that in general Views tend to change after a couple of releases and you'll quickly need to create a separate ViewModel for each View. Again, this is not a requirement of MVVM; it is good old object orientation.

Comment: On my current setup, the listbox for both Examples and Exercises is very similar, they are just bound to different objects (different properties), other than that they are the same. What View can I use that should work for both objects or reuse for each object? Or am I wroing to think I can use just 1 View for both objects?

Comment: If the bindings are different (properties) it become harder to reuse the listbox. One way to reuse it is by defining a DataTemplate for an example and one for an Exercise. In the listbox (view) assign both datatemplates. The correct one will be selected by WPF. Note that this is an option, as soon as you want the listbox to have different behaviour or added visuals you will make two user controls.

Comment: Thanks, will try that out. But in a Window, can I use two instances of a single View? Since I am using a TabControl, 1 tab for Example and 1 tab for Exercises. And in each tab there is a listbox for showing the records.

Comment: Of course. Do not worry about what is or is not allowed,use what you need and try to keep responsibilities apart.